# What is the definition of energy-independent basis?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, orbitals, terminology

I am reading this article by Zatsarinny and Fischer [[1](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-4075/33/3/303)].
At some point they span a wave function $\Psi_{E}$ in terms of *energy independent basis*

$$\Psi_{E}=\sum_{k} A_{E k} \Psi_{k}$$

For example, *The Structures of Binary Compounds* mentions that LCAO is an energy-independent basis [2] ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hc3-BAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+Structures+of+Binary+Compounds&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%22energy-independent%20basis%22&f=false)):

> The non-linearity of the one-electron eigenvalue problem represents a
> considerable complication of this scheme, which does not occur if an
> energy-independent basis set, such as the LCAO, is used.

What is the *energy-independent basis*?

#### Reference

1. Zatsarinny, O.; Fischer, C. F. The Use of Basis Splines and Non-Orthogonal Orbitals in $R$-Matrix Calculations: Application to Li Photoionization. *J. Phys. B: At. Mol. Opt. Phys.* **2000**, 33 (3), 313–341. DOI: [10.1088/0953-4075/33/3/303](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-4075/33/3/303).
2. *The Structures of Binary Compounds*; Boer, F. R. de, Pettifor, D. G., Hafner, J., Eds.; Cohesion and structure; North-Holland: Amsterdam, **1989**. ISBN 978-0-444-87478-8.